# How to use reflection to retrieve private variable property from JPA objects

Tags: java, jpa, reflection

One of my goals is to create an engine that will set values in pojo object from JPA objects dynamically using reflection. One of the matching criteria is, that the field names should match.

I was successfully able to implement this for two pojo objects. But when I tried using JPA objects as one of the object parameter, it didn't work. Based on my research I found out that the method `Class.getDeclaredFields()` , does not give me the name of the field but the getter/setter method name of member variable for JPA objects.

Can anyone please give me a lead or direction as in where/what should I look to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA providers will often use [dynamic proxy classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) of your concrete JPA classes, so you have no guarantee of the field names in the proxy. The only guarantee about a proxy is that the *methods* are the same. Use a debugger to inspect the runtime class of the JPA class instances that you're trying to use and you'll see the problem.

The best you'll be able to do is use reflection to call methods on JPA-returned objects.

---

<sub>All that aside, I don't really see why you'd need to POJO-ify an entity class anyway, since an entity is primarily an annotated... POJO.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Matt that worked. The reason we have to create pojo -DTO class is to decouple the client dependencies on our domain model objects.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the matching criteria is, that the field names should match.

I think that this is the root of your problem.  There is simply no guarantee that a Java object's field names will match the names of getters and setters ... or anything else.  If you make this assumption, you will run into cases where is doesn't work.

The best solution is to simply not use this approach.  Make it a requirement that the Pojo classes conform to the JavaBeans spec and rely on the setters to set the properties.  This is likely to work more often than making assumptions about (private) field names.

---

In fact, the state of a generic JPA object implemented using a dynamic proxies could well be held in a hash map.  Those fields you can see could simply be constants used for something else.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help later I found something very similar to what i wanted to achieve http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html